Thermostat from one zone turns heating on all zones
Recently moved in a home with a 6-zone heating system using gas and water baseboards. All works well, except when I turn heating on thermostat for zone 3. When I do that, all zones are heating (even though their respective thermostats are off). Below is the wiring behind the thermostat zone 3:

This thermostat controls no cooling.
Note that there are two sets of cables coming out of the wall and a jump between R and RC. Interestingly, thermostat manual says "Remove metal jumper if you have both R and Rc wires."
And the Taco board:

Taco device in basement only shows “zone 3” enabled when this thermostat is heating and other valves remain "cold".
Any thoughts on where is this behaviour coming from? I'd like for this thermostat to only control its zone, and leave the others alone.
My current theories are:

this double cabling has something to do with it. Though unlikely. If this zone would enable other zones, it would show on the Taco board, right?
zone 3 pipes actually covers the whole home (as in "double piped") but quite unlikely. Who would do that just because?
something is opening the other zones, past the Taco (as other zones show off on the Taco). Is that possible?

Here is a picture of the valves/circulator pumps installation:

11/11 update
I have turned all heating and waited 8h. Then turned thermostat zone 3 only. Here are pictures and thermo-pictures:

Here is the thermo view a few minutes after turning heating on zone 3:

Here is a few minutes later:

Looks like 3, 4 and 5 are getting hot water through.

Multiple cables may only mean they needed more wires than were available in one cable at the time. This also depends on how the other ends of the cables are wired. A picture of the Taco end of this gaggle may help, too. Also, model numbers of the thermostat and Taco board, so instruction manuals may be perused.

Thermostat is Honeywell RTH2300b. Picture of the Taco board added to initial post. Not sure of the exact Taco model, but it looks like the ZVC406-4. Thank you!

Thanks for the pictures and model #'s. Which cables in the Taco picture are the cables coming from the thermostat?

When you say "other valves remain 'cold'", do you mean the lights on the Taco board are off, or do you mean they are literally cold to the touch, with no hot water passing through them?

@Triplefault, the thermostat cables  are going to the zone 3 section of the Taco board. Interestingly, once I had only zoned 3 heating on, I checked the voltage of each of the zone at the top of the board and all had ~24v except zone 3 which was at 0v. I assumed the zone is On when getting 0v.

@Mark, I mean both: leds on the taco board are off except zone 3 and the valves showed not above 30F on a thermo device. Zone 3 was at 90F. Though I could recheck that last fact tomorrow to confirm.

@thoma If the hot water is not flowing through the other zone valves, it sure seems to point to a plumbing issue.  Are the valves all in one location with manifolds for supply and return?  Can you add a photo?

@Mark Sorry for the latency of my response. Yep, all valves are in a single location. I've looked into it further and they are actually not valves but circulator pumps - not sure it changes anything... I will add details and photos in main post.

@thoma - are the pumps on the supply side or the return side?

@Mark Given their temps is close to 100F, I’d say on the supply side.

@Mark - Pumps have an arrow pointing up, confirming my previous comment. Supply side.

@thoma - Can you tell if the pumps are running in zones 4 and 5 when only 3 is on?

@Mark - Just did some tests right now. Pointed a screwdriver onto the various pumps, handle on my ear, I can confirm only pump 3 is actually pumping. I confirmed this is accurate by testing other zones on/off to actually hear the sound difference. Conclusion only zone 3 is pumping.
